# How to customize jquery ui autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery ui autocomplete, and for the list of terms that appears in the dropdown, is there a way so that you can categorize the terms? Basically what I want is: In the dropdown menu, depending on what category a term is from, its background color will be a certain color. Something like you define a dictionary like:

```
var dictionary = {"apple":"red", "banana":"yellow"};
```

Then, you pass this to the jquery ui autocomplete initializer, and the dropdown will have the terms `apple` having a red background color, and `banana` with a yellow background color.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely possible take a look at this [Jquery-ui-Autocomplete Catagories](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories)

now the basic gist is this:

```
<style>
    .ui-autocomplete-category {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: .2em .4em;
    margin: .8em 0 .2em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    }
</style>
<script>
  $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
       _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
             var that = this,
             currentCategory = "";
             $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
                 if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                      ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                      currentCategory = item.category;
                      }
                  that._renderItemData( ul, item );
             });
       }
   });
</script>
<script>
   $(function() {
   var data = [
     { label: "anders", category: "" },
     { label: "andreas", category: "" },
     { label: "antal", category: "" },
     { label: "annhhx10", category: "Products" },
     { label: "annk K12", category: "Products" },
     { label: "annttop C13", category: "Products" },
     { label: "anders andersson", category: "People" },
     { label: "andreas andersson", category: "People" },
     { label: "andreas johnson", category: "People" }
  ];

   $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
     delay: 0,
     source: data
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body> 
   <label for="search">Search: </label>
   <input id="search" />
</body>
```

Now what you want to do is change up the `.ui-autocomplete-catagory` CSS class to get the general idea of a category, in order to get specific categories to have different colors you will need to add their own CSS classes. You could use jQuery to do this or have them concretely added on the add of each categories in the `ul.append()` in the first script above.